# UIPickerView reusing view is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

According to Apples API references reusing view in this method

```
optional func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, 
          viewForRow row: Int, 
        forComponent component: Int, 
             reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView
```

is a cached view by picker view but when I'm trying to use it for next rows it's always nil while I'm returning a `UILabel` when reusing view is nil. What is the problem?
this is my implementation:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()
    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    pickerLabel.text = "10"
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    pickerLabel.sizeToFit()
    return pickerLabel
}
```

Comment: Update your question with your complete implementation of this method.

Comment: post edited @maddy

Comment: Where's your attempt to use `view` if it's provided?

Comment: why dont you upvote the accepted answer? this user took his time to help you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code makes no attempt to use the reuse view. Your code should be something like this:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    var pickerLabel : UILabel
    if let label = view as? UILabel {
        pickerLabel = label
    } else {
        pickerLabel = UILabel()
        pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        pickerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    }

    pickerLabel.text = "10"
    pickerLabel.sizeToFit()

    return pickerLabel
}
```

This code reuses the label if the reuse view is a label. Otherwise it creates and sets up a new label.

Note that a picker will only pass in a reuse view as the picker view is scrolled. It's similar to a table view's cell reuse.

Comment: when I write `print(view)` in that function it always print nil. so it never gets to the if statement

Comment: How many rows are in your picker view? Are you checking `view` when you scroll the picker view?

Comment: I've added 50 fake rows and yes I'm scrolling and every time it prints nil

Comment: It is an implementation detail. There is no guarantee the picker will reuse any views. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks Works like Charm